# Start/stop a deployment in Weblogic 9 using JMX (or WLST)

Tags: weblogic, jmx, mbeans, wlst

I want to start/stop a deployment in weblogic 9 server.
I prefer to use JMX to talk to a weblogic MBean. I already use this to start/stop a server, but I cannot find the MBean for starting/stopping deployments/applications.

In weblogic server 11g there is a AppDeploymentRuntimeMBean which can stop/start deployments. That is described here:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13951/mbeans/AppDeploymentRuntimeMBean.html

But I cannot find a simular MBean in weblogic 9 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/wlsmbeanref/core/index.html

Is there a way to start/stop a weblogic 9 deployment using jmx or wlst?

BTW, when I record a WLST-script during start/stop of a deployment the pyton-script is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually AppDeploymentRuntimeMBean was first introduced in WLS 10.3 version. And this bean along with DeploymentManagerMBean were created to replace DeployerRuntimeMBean (it is considered deprecated since 9.0.0.0 version). As for me it seems that there is no way to start\stop applications with JMX on WLS 9 unless you decide to use deprecated API. And also consider the fact that you need Administration Server running in order to access Domain Runtime MBean Server that will provide an entry point to DeployerRuntimeMBean.